# How to prevent INotifyPropertyChanged calling itself

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged

First, the target is C#.

I’d like a custom object to be able to notify listeners (other classes) when a property on the object is changed. The obvious solution from searching is the INotifyPropertyChanged, but I’m not certain it’s the answer.

There are 2 or more classes which change an object. For simplicity, say one is the network and one is a textbox. They change a property in myObject, which triggers INotifyPropertyChanged via the setter.

The point is, if the network class initiates the change, I don’t then want the network class to be notified, and if the textbox initiates the change, I only want the network to be notified, not the textbox.

I can’t believe someone hasn’t come across this before, but I can’t find anything which matches the scenario.

What’s the best way round this?

Edited as it was closed as a duplicate but none of the suggested answers have anything to do with the question.

Multiple “setter” classes can make changes to any number of objects, which then trigger a notification to the interested “listener” classes. The listener classes ARE the setter classes. I need a way to only notify the listeners which didn’t set the property. Otherwise I get an endless loop!

Comment: You should limit your question to "what is **one** way around this", otherwise it's going to be an opinionated answer, which might get your question closed. One way would be to make each of the objects aware that they are are provoking a change in the object, and thus not react to that event from it. In other words, set a boolean field to true, do the change, if the event handler is called when the field is true, ignore it, after you've changed the value, set the field back to false.

Comment: Thanks, sorry, one way will do :)

I’d like it to be able to handle any number of “changers” but the central object handle the messaging. It somehow needs to know which changer initiated the change, which I can’t do through getters and setters. Perhaps I could use methods for all the properties, and include the sender object as a parameter. Is there a better way, though?

Comment: There are lots of options. As a general rule, the approach is to only raise the event if the value has in fact changed. There are numerous examples of how to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` already on Stack Overflow, including many that take this approach. See marked duplicate for an example of my own contribution to the mix, along with some other good ideas.

Comment: For such cases I use flag, which I check then whether I should trigger PropertyChanged or not

Comment: for subscription I might have a method like this public void SubscribePropertyChanged(string propertyName, Action handler)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (args.PropertyName == propertyName)
                {
                    if (notificationEnabled)
                    {
                        handler();
                    }
                }
            };
        }

Comment: then in the place I set property I would set notificationEnabled = false; myObject.Property= "whatever"; notificationEnabled = true;

Comment: @PeterDuniho I'm not sure the answer for "Better way to trigger ..." actually answers this question. I understand the problem is in cycle calls, while that question is "Is there a way to do this that would require less code?"

Comment: @Viktor: the answer to this question is, essentially, "implement the interface correctly". Cycles don't happen if you only actually raise the event when the value changes, as any good implementation of the interface will take care to do. If you would like to propose a different duplicate that you feel is more on the mark, be my guest. The fact is, the question itself, taken literally, is too broad to have been suitable to be on Stack Overflow in the first place. In the interest of actually _helping_, I've provided one of the better Q&A I know of that addresses their need.

Comment: Perhaps I’m not explaining myself. Apologies. The problem is not that the event is being triggered when the property hasn’t changed. The problem is that multiple “managers” can drive changes to any of a collection of objects, which need to notify all the other managers, but not the one that changed the property.

Comment: As an example, a mechanic object changes one of the car objects. The owner of the car needs to know about the change. The driver needs to know about the change. The mechanic already knows because he changed it. So the driver should be notified, the owner should be notified, but not the mechanic. In another case, the driver might cause the change, in which case the other 2 listeners need to know. Does this example help explain it better?

Answer (score 0):

You can use invocator like that:

```
[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
    var stackFrames = stackTrace.GetFrames().Skip(1);  
    foreach (var d in PropertyChanged?.GetInvocationList() ?? new Delegate[0])
    {
        if (stackFrames?.Any(f => f.GetMethod().ReflectedType.GUID == d.Target.GetType().GUID)??false) continue;
        d.Method.Invoke(d,new object[]{ d, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName) });
    }
}
```

Or check in your network class that the current value of the property is not equal to the value that was set.

Comment: Thank you. The difficulty with checking in the network class is that it doesn’t hold a copy of all the objects or all the object’s values to know whether it has changed or not. I’ll look into the StackTrace idea. It seems obvious to me that the initiator of a change to an object does not need to be notified about changes it initiates :)

Comment: @AmateurD Have you solved this problem?

Comment: Hi Vadim, not yet done, I will either follow up with your suggestion (I have read it but don’t really understand it yet) or split it so that the property will be set, then a separate method will be called by the listener (managers) to trigger broadcasting INotifyPropertyChanged and include the manager as the Sender. That way when the listener (manager) class receives the notification it can compare it with itself and disregard any notifications it knows it generated. Thanks